# Seachview buscar dados do fragmento

Tags: android, material-design

No aplicativo possui toolbar e 2 tabs por meio do TabLayout com 1 fragmento em cada tab.

Eu quero colocar a biblioteca MaterialSearchView para implementar o searchview que vai ser feita pesquisando os itens do recyclerview que está na TAB Telefones .

Porém coloco o MaterialSearchView na activity_main.xml

```
<com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar
    style="@style/MaterialSearchBarLight"
    app:mt_speechMode="false"
    app:mt_hint="Pesquisar telefones"
    app:mt_maxSuggestionsCount="10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/searchBar" />
```

Quando tento usar o MaterialSearchBar pelo fragmento da null point exception.

Eu tenho que colocar o MaterialSearchBar no xml da fragment ou tem algum modo de 
usar no xml da activity?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver deixando o MaterialSearchBar no xml da actionbar e coloquei no fragmento desse jeito.

Antes

```
materialSearchBar = (MaterialSearchBar) view.findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
```

Mudei para

```
materialSearchBar = (MaterialSearchBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
```